# People with a magical sword killing cops

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I heard this story on some podcast in the last ten years, I think even in the last five years. I thought it was on [PodCastle](https://podcastle.org/), but I can't find it in their archive.

Anyway, the story is about a man and a woman (the man is black, and the woman is either black or Latina) who find a cursed sword and some other magical weapon that really wants to kill people and gives them invisibility and maybe other abilities so long as they keep feeding the weapons with death. They then proceed to use the weapons to kill cops. They start traveling the country, following reports of police brutality as scary avenging angels.

I think the story begins with the woman getting a call from some NY city bureaucrat to go clean out her deceased great-aunt's apartment in public housing - for some reason she has just one day to do it before city maintenance will just throw everything out, so she needs a ride all the way out to where her relative lived and that's why her ex is with her (he drove her) when she finds the weapons.